# How do I display tooltip text for HTML <input> element using CSS style and data-title attribute?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to display tooltip like text using the data-title attribute for an HTML  control.

I used the following technique for a  element, and it works fine.

**HTML Element:**

```
<span class="spanNewID" data-title="Tooltip Text">816631-20319G14440 </span>
```

**CSS Style:**

```
span.spanNewID[data-title]:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.1s ease 0.5s;
    visibility: visible;
}

span.spanNewID[data-title]:after {
    content: attr(data-title);
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 1px 5px 2px 5px;
    bottom: -1.6em;
    left: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #222222;
    opacity: 0;
    border: 1px solid #111111;
    z-index: 99999;
    visibility: hidden;
}

span.spanNewID[data-title] {
    position: relative;
}
```

The above code snippet works to correctly display my css based tooltip.

I am trying to apply the same selector to an  element.
Consider the following:

**HTML Element:**

```
<input type="submit" value="Click Me" class="inuse" data-title="Input ELement Help"> </input>
```

**CSS Style:**

```
input.inuse[data-title]:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.1s ease 0.5s;
    visibility: visible;
}

input.inuse[data-title]:after {
    content: attr(data-title);
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 1px 5px 2px 5px;
    bottom: -1.6em;
    left: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #222222;
    opacity: 0;
    border: 1px solid #111111;
    z-index: 99999;
    visibility: hidden;
}

input.inuse[data-title] {
    position: relative;
}
```

The hover text/tooltip does not display in this case.
I do not see any errors. There are no visible changes on the page.
I attempted to use the css selector in the **Chrome** "**CSS Selector Tester**" and the selector works as expected.

What am I missing/doing wrong here?

Thanks,JohnB

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response. I did Google it, came up with the solution, attempted to get it to work and provided  a workable example. Nice job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit of Googling myself, and came up with some interesting information. First off, [pseduo-selectors :before and :after should be used on container elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660434/8273686).

Potentially you could use `<button></button>` instead of `<input>` and achieve the effect you desire:

```css
.inuse[data-title]:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.1s ease 0.5s;
    visibility: visible;
}

.inuse[data-title]:after {
    content: attr(data-title);
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 1px 5px 2px 5px;
    bottom: -1.6em;
    left: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #222222;
    opacity: 0;
    border: 1px solid #111111;
    z-index: 99999;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.inuse[data-title] {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" value="Click Me" class="inuse" data-title="Input ELement Help">Click Me</button>
```

Or, and I'm sure you've considered this but it's worth mentioning anyway, just use the `title` attribute:

```html
<input type="submit" value="Click Me" class="inuse" data-title="Input ELement Help" title="Input ELement Help">
```

Comment: Discussion of that here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/can-i-use-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-on-an-input-field

Comment: Frish:  Thank you so much for getting back to me. Due to existin design, I have to use asp.net buttons in a gridview. We'll have to live with unformatted tooltip text for those. Thx JB

Comment: I know the feeling! Good luck with your project :)